# How to make rails radio button thats not checked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to make a radio button in rails using:

`<%= f.radio_button :category_id, "1" %>`

The problem is it's checked by default, and I don't want the user to be able to submit a form without explicitly clicking one first (basically i want it unchecked when the page loads)

the problem is if it errors out, and the page reloads, if i add `:checked => false` that seems to overwrite what the user had entered before getting an error, and they have to click it again.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to pertain the state of the checked button, you have to save that somehow and get that information back to the view. 
You can do that manually, or let the radio_button handle that as described at [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/radio_button)

```
# Let's say that @post.category returns "rails":
radio_button("post", "category", "rails")
radio_button("post", "category", "java")
# => <input type="radio" id="post_category_rails" name="post[category]" value="rails" checked="checked" />
#    <input type="radio" id="post_category_java" name="post[category]" value="java" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`FormBuilder` helpers (which you're using every time you call an input method on the block argument oh a `form_for`) will always reflect the current value of the corresponding attribute. So:

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :category_id, "1" %>
```

…will only be checked if `@post.category_id == "1"`

It sounds like what you want to do is make sure the state of your model is correct before you render the view.